# spring security with HMAC?

Tags: encryption, spring-security

HMAC seems to be the ideal security for a stateless webapp, storing nothing in server sessions.

But is it possible to integrate HMAC auth with Spring Security auth ?

I am currently using Spring Security 3.1.0

Comment: A HMAC is interesting for sure, but it is even more interesting how you would get the key at the client without showing it to everybody listening in, let alone hackers playing man in the middle. SSL has of course integrity/authentication checks build in, but SSL sessions themselves are not stateless. Neither is a MAC actually, because if you "sign" multiple messages you are prone to replay attacks if you don't include a NONCE of sorts.

Comment: @owlstead: Do you have any suggestion on good auth/integrity checks for stateless webapps/webservices ? http basic / digests are OK (although i prefer form auth for the presentation flexibility), but having to restart the browser to change the credentials are simply uncomfortable to me.

Comment: There always has been a lot of discussion going on about this, but basically it boils down to the fact that you cannot really do this in a browser, you will have to go for some scheme involving SSL. It becomes easier to get authentication to work if you have a native client of course.

Comment: Same question posted at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?120995-spring-security-with-HMAC

Comment: For backend only (no browser) see this example of doing HMAC w/ Spring Security: https://github.com/ryantenney/spring-rest-hmac/tree/master/src/main/java/com/ericsson/erifly/security